# (Written on VS for Windows forms): is it bad practice to declare variables in a public partial class?

Tags: c#, .net

Should it be avoided in the same sense that globals should be avoided? I'm using .NET for this. Below is my code:

```
namespace SUDOKU_
{
    public partial class frmSudoku : Form
    {
        //I WANT TO DECLARE VARIABLES HERE

        public frmSudoku()
        {
            //irrelevant code
        }
        //more irrelevant code
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure what a public partial class is, but I have heard of class level variables in C# (which I presume is something like this, where a variable can be accessed by all functions of a class). Would I be making something like a class-level variable (i.e. not bad practice)?

Comment: There's nothing wrong here. A *partial* class is just a class split into two or more files.

Comment: What's wrong in this example is the CaSiNg, for which PascalCase is considered standard in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

partial just means, that not all of the content of a class is defined in this file. If you have a look at your "InitializeComponent"-Method and press F12 in it, you'll see that there is a second file, created by Visual Studio, in which the Items from the Designer are defined.

That means every member-variable you'll define in either of those two files acts like a member Variable would in a class which is not partial.

It is not bad practice to define member variables in this class (don't define it in the auto-generated file though)